# Z3 Prover (Python bindings) can't determine negated Modus Ponens when proof=True

Tags: python, z3, proof, z3py

I'm trying to understand why the Z3 Solver returns "unknown" when trying to satisfy the following inconsistent set of expressions.

```
In [1]: from z3 import *

In [2]: set_param(proof=True)

In [3]: s = Solver()

In [4]: p,q = Bools("p q")

In [5]: s.add(p)

In [6]: s.add(Not(q))

In [7]: s.add(Implies(p,q))

In [8]: s.check()
Out[8]: unknown
```

Note that we do not get "unknown" when do not set the proof param to True

```
In [1]: from z3 import *

In [2]: s = Solver()

In [3]: p,q = Bools("p q")

In [4]: s.add(p)

In [5]: s.add(Not(q))

In [6]: s.add(Implies(p,q))

In [7]: s.check()
Out[7]: unsat
```

Furthermore, we do not get "unknown" when we use a different inconsistent set of expressions even when setting proof=True:

```
In [1]: from z3 import *

In [2]: set_param(proof=True)

In [3]: s = Solver()

In [4]: x = Int('x')

In [5]: s.add(x==0)

In [6]: s.add(x>0)

In [7]: s.check()
Out[7]: unsat
```

What is problematic about setting up this inconsistent set of expressions in sentential logic while the proof param is set to True?